# Invoke python script from node.js using python-shell

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-3.x

I am very new to both python and node.js. Basically I am trying to call a python script from node.js.Any help would be much appreciated.

I have installed python-shell npm package.

When I run the python script from cmd, it works fine and I can see the output.
I have installed python 3.8.

This is my python script:

```
# script.py
my_name = 'Lily'
my_age = 22
my_height = 172 # cm
my_weight = 71 # kg
my_eyes = 'Brown'
my_teeth = 'White'
my_hair = 'Black'

print ("Let's talk about %s." % my_name)
print ("He's %d centimeters tall." % my_height)
print ("He's %d kilograms heavy." % my_weight)
print ("Actually that's not too heavy.")
print ("He's got %s eyes and %s hair." % (my_eyes, my_hair))
print ("His teeth are usually %s depending on the coffee." % my_teeth)

# this line is tricky, try to get it exactly right
print ("If I add %d, %d, and %d I get %d. I don't know what that means but, whatever." % (
    my_age, my_height, my_weight, my_age + my_height + my_weight))
```

Here is my node.js script:

```
function Runpy(){
  var {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
  var options = {
    mode: 'text',
    pythonPath: 'C:/Users/User1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38', 
    pythonOptions: ['-u'],
    scriptPath: 'C:/PythonScripts/script.py'
  };

  PythonShell.run('script.py', options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
    console.log('results: %j', results);
  });
}
return Runpy();
```

When I run `node ./sample.js` I get the following error:

> events.js:174
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>
> Error: spawn C:/Users/User1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38 ENOENT
>
> at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
>   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>   at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
>   at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
>   at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
>
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>   at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
>   at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
>   [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
>   at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

I have referred to this stackoverflow post [Using PythonShell module in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268541/using-pythonshell-module-in-nodejs) where it is suggested to use absolute path to the script and also correct path to the python executable which i am doing but still getting the above error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. The path to the python executable was incomplete. I was just pointing to 'C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38' which should be 'C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python3'. Indeed a silly mistake